# Node.js Cannot find module when refactoring method into separate file

Tags: node.js, npm

This has been asked a lot and I still can't wrap my head around it.

My old, working code:
database-setup.mjs file in /

```
import sqlite3 from 'sqlite3';
import { open } from 'sqlite'
(async () => {
  // open the database
  const db = await open({
    filename: './mydb.sqlite',
    driver: sqlite3.Database,
  });
  await db.migrate({ force: true });
  const people = await db.all('SELECT * FROM person');
  console.log("All People:", JSON.stringify(people, null, 2));

  const vehicles = await db.all('SELECT * FROM vehicle');
  console.log("All Vehicles:", JSON.stringify(vehicles, null, 2));
})();
```

I have a lot of db calls, so I thought I refactor the open method into a separate file.

resulting in this file under /src/lib/db.ts

```
import sqlite3 from 'sqlite3'
import { open } from 'sqlite'

export async function openDB () {
    return open({
        filename: 'mydb.sqlite',
        driver: sqlite3.Database
    })
}
```

and the previous file from the top now looks like this:

```
import { openDB } from './src/lib/db'

(async () => {
  // open the database   
  const db= await openDB();

  await db.migrate({ force: true });

  const people = await db.all('SELECT * FROM person');
  console.log("All People:", JSON.stringify(people, null, 2));

  const vehicles = await db.all('SELECT * FROM vehicle');
  console.log("All Vehicles:", JSON.stringify(vehicles, null, 2));
})();
```

running this now results in

```
Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module 'D:\Programming\nextjs\nextjs-basics\src\lib\db' imported from D:\Programming\nextjs\nextjs-basics\database-setup.mjs
```

My Node version is >14.0.
The path is correct, I see the file ts file there. I do not see any compile file, but I think that's normal? So I don't understand why it is not finding the module?

The tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "include": [
    "next-env.d.ts",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx"
  ]
}
```

Comment: `/src/lib/db.ts` how do you run compile your typescript code?

Comment: `npm run build` if typescript code changes, than usually just `npm run dev`

Comment: What is the target folder for `tsc`?  You need to target compiled file.

Comment: I'll put this in the original post since its hard to read it. You are saying I should include an outputDir/rootDir to tsc, right?

Comment: I just read into it, and by default the compiled files get saved in the same folder as the ts files, so shouldn't it work by default? @YuryTarabanko

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve it:

So I had to rename the db.ts file into db.mjs - problem solved.
But now I am running `.js` files, even though I wanted a 100% `ts` coverage.

The - in my eyes - proper way to actually tackle the problem instead of avoiding it:

1. Install `ts-node`
2. Create an additional tsconfig (to avoid interference with frameworks, IE11 Polymorph stuff etc) and add this to it:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2017",
    "module": "CommonJS"
  }
}
```

Change your package.json `dev` command accordingly, e.g. for me this was changing
`"dev": "node ./database-setup.mjs && next dev"`
into
`"dev": "ts-node --project ./tsconfig-node.json ./database-setup.ts && next dev"`
Both db.ts and database-setup.ts are now in typescript and everything works.

Comment: this is not the final answer yet. There is another way, that makes it possible to use ts files, even in these non-production database setup files.  
I'll play around a bit and edit this answer then.